# Bootstrap 4 Visibility Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

Starting to learn Bootstrap 4 and its responsive grid system, the code below shows my basic container class.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-4 box1">1</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box2">2</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-sm-up col-12 box4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first row is working perfectly fine, however my second row I am trying to make just visible on xs screensizes. Tried looking on Bootstrap's webpage and can't see where my error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `d-block d-sm-none` bootstrap4.beta class. It will display the element below `sm` breakpoint

***Stack Snippet***

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-4 box1">1</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box2">2</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-block d-sm-none col-12 box4">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[***Reference Link***](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Is there any specific reason the hidden class doesn't work when it says on the Bootstrap website that it's the replacement of 'visible-*-*'? I also can't seem to find anything about 'd-block d-sm-none' online, do you know any useful links to help me better understand? Thanks again.

Comment: @JackCawthra actually `hidden` classes are no longer in bootstrap4 beta version...if you are using bootstrap4 aplha version the hidden classes will work...